# About the meaning of perl \w

Tags: regex, perl

according to the doc

> \w        [3]  Match a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_", plus
>   other connector punctuation chars plus Unicode marks)

I don't understand what is "plus other connector punctuation chars plus Unicode marks", the doc seems doesn't say. What is `\w` really?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 119,821 matching characters in Unicode 9.0.0 (included in Perl 5.26.0):

```
$ unichars -a -u '\w' | wc -l
119821
```

You can use `unichars` to list the characters matching a property, and you can use `uniprops` to list the properties that match a character. Both are provided by [Unicode::Tussle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode::Tussle).

---

[perluniprops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html) documents `\p`, and `\w` is short for `\p{XPosixWord}`<sup>[1]</sup>, so this is the document one should consult to find out more about `\w` and other properties.

A sufficiently-recent perluniprops<sup>[2]</sup> documents that `\w` consists of the union of the following properties:

- `XPosixWord`:

  - `XPosixAlnum`: Alphabetic and decimal digits.

    - `Alphabetic`
    - `Decimal_Number`: Decimal digits.
  - `Mark`
  - `Connector_Punctuation`
  - `Join_Control`

Verification:

```
$ diff -u \
   <( unichars -a -u '\w' ) \
   <( unichars -a -u '[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Mark}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]' ) \
      && echo "No difference."
No difference.
```

---

In detail:

- Custom derived property `XPosixWord`:

  - Custom derived property `XPosixAlnum`: Alphabetic and decimal digits.

    - Derived property `Alphabetic`:

      - Derived property `Uppercase`:

        - General category `Uppercase_Letter` (`Lu`)
        - `Other_Uppercase`<sup>[3]</sup>
      - Derived property `Lowercase`:

        - General category `Lowercase_Letter` (`Ll`)
        - `Other_Lowercase`<sup>[3]</sup>
      - General category `Titlecase_Letter` (`Lt`)
      - General category `Modifier_Letter` (`Lm`)
      - General category `Other_Letter` (`Lo`)
      - General category `Letter_Number` (`Nl`)
      - `Other_Alphabetic`<sup>[3]</sup>
    - General category `Decimal_Number` (`Nd`): Decimal digits.
  - General category `Mark` (`M`):

    - General category `Spacing_Mark` (`Mc`)
    - General category `Enclosing_Mark` (`Me`)
    - General category `Nonspacing_Mark` (`Mn`)
  - General category `Connector_Punctuation` (`Pc`)
  - `Join_Control`

---

1. When using `/u` or `use feature qw( unicode_strings );`.
2. 5.28 will be the first version that documents `XPosixWord` correctly (since `Join_Control` characters were added to it in 5.18).
3. Not exposed by Perl.

Comment: Hi, @ikegami. Where is `unichars`? I can not install it using apt. Then I download Unicode::Tussle., there is a unichars script. But `unichars -a -u '\w'` doesn't work

Comment: The documentation is fixed in blead: https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commitdiff/9b79e9e3431d11e79a4f85268f70130b7b4369f6

Comment: @user15964, What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Keep in mind that `unichars` can be slow, especially with `-a` and `-u`. It literally applies the regex argument against each of the 0x110000 possible Unicode characters.

Comment: @melpomene, Thanks

Comment: @ikegami Oh, I understand what is going on. it really works. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your quote is from [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-Classes-and-other-Special-Escapes). The corresponding footnote says:

> - [3]
>     See [Backslash sequences in perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Backslash-sequences) for details.

Which says:

> A `\w` matches a single alphanumeric character (an alphabetic character, or a decimal digit); or a connecting punctuation character, such as an underscore ("_"); or a "mark" character (like some sort of accent) that attaches to one of those. It does not match a whole word. To match a whole word, use `\w+`. This isn't the same thing as matching an English word, but in the ASCII range it is the same as a string of Perl-identifier characters.

It also says that (if Unicode rules are in effect), `\w` is equivalent to `\p{Word}`. [`perldoc perluniprops`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-%5cp%7b%7d-and-%5cP%7b%7d):

> ```
> \p{Word}                \p{XPosixWord}
> ```

I.e. `\p{Word}` is an alias for `\p{XPosixWord}`.

> ```
> \p{XPosixWord}          \w, including beyond ASCII; = \p{Alnum} + \pM + \p{Pc} (Short: \p{Word})
> ```

I.e. `\p{XPosixWord}` is the union of `\p{Alnum}`, `\pM`, and `\p{Pc}`.

Here `\p{Alnum}` matches any "*Alphabetic and (decimal) Numeric*" character, `\pM` matches any character whose general category is "Mark", and `\p{Pc}` matches any character whose general category is "Connector Punctuation".

For a complete list of characters in those categories I'll have to defer to Unicode.

Comment: @ikegami I'm pretty sure "Word" is not a Unicode property.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I didn't expect that it can related to so much things. But anyway, can we simply print out `\pM` and `\p{Pc}`. At the moment, I still don't get any sense what a character belong to `\pM` or `\p{PC}` looks like